# Co-occurrences in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple network in which each node has `dui` and `name` property and each relation has `year` and `freq` (frequency) property.

For example, if I wish to create ego network for node with `dui = 'D000003'`, I use the following query (please note that I limit the number of results with `WHERE` clause):

```
MATCH (n {dui:'D000003'})<-[r]->(m) WHERE r.year = 2005 AND r.freq > 20 RETURN n.dui, m.dui;
```

and the corresponding result is:

```
+-----------------------+
| n.dui     | m.dui     |
+-----------------------+
| "D000003" | "D015995" |
| "D000003" | "D015169" |
| "D000003" | "D013552" |
| "D000003" | "D008460" |
| "D000003" | "D006801" |
| "D000003" | "D005516" |
| "D000003" | "D005506" |
| "D000003" | "D002418" |
| "D000003" | "D002417" |
| "D000003" | "D000818" |
+-----------------------+
```

Now I wonder how to get all relationships between nodes which are listed under the `m.dui` column; in other words I wish to produce co-occurrence graph for those nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n { dui:'D000003' })-[r]-(m)
WHERE r.year = 2005 AND r.freq > 20
MATCH (n)-[rel]-(m)
RETURN n.dui, m.dui, COLLECT(rel) AS rels;
```

Note that I changed your weird (and, I believe, undocumented) `<-[r]->` syntax to `-[r]-`, which means the directionality does not matter.

Comment: Actually this works, but I need all possible relationships between nodes which are listed under the `m.dui` column.